# How to add foreign key in a model using ASP.NET ( MVC6 framework)

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am new to ASP.NET and trying out the new MVC 6 framework. i want to create an To do list App. After user authentication, I am redirecting to a dashboard page where I want to display to do tasks. I have created a model Task, but i am unsure about how to add a Foreign Key for the user id so that when i redirect the user to the dashboard page I can query based on the user's id.

```
public class Task
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // i want to add a fk to aspnetuser id here 
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I don't think so you can directly set the value of model by foreign key. you need to set id to your session or cookie or something else, because whenever you try to access this model you need to create new object of the class. you will get null value

Answer (score 3):

```
public class Task
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int AnyNameForId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AnyNameForId")] 
    public AspnetUser User { get; set; }
}

public class AspnetUser
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: In order for the annotation to work, need to be sure to include: 
"using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;"

Answer (score 0):

suppose u have class XYZ having Id as primary key.

now u want to class XYZ's Id as foreign key in class ABC,

So, it can be done like writing the following in class ABC

```
public Guid XYZId{get;set;} 
public XYZ xyz{get;set;}`
```

xyz is an object of class XYZ.
.net core will automatically take XYZId as fk in class ABC.....PLZ note that Id Should be the primary in class XYZ